# Parse XML in SQL Server resulting in NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I'm trying to parse an XML file in a SQL Server 2014 stored procedure.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
        <APPLICATION_ID>9204797</APPLICATION_ID>
        <ACTIVITY>R44</ACTIVITY>
        <ADMINISTERING_IC>AI</ADMINISTERING_IC>
        <APPLICATION_TYPE>5</APPLICATION_TYPE>
        <ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
        <AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>01/11/2017</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
        <BUDGET_START>01/01/2017</BUDGET_START>
        <BUDGET_END>12/31/2017</BUDGET_END>
    </row>
</PROJECT>
```

And my code is

```
SELECT 
    nref.value('@APPLICATION_ID[1]','varchar(max)') APPLICATION_ID,
    nref.value('@ACTIVITY[1]','varchar(max)') ACTIVITY                  
FROM 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('//PROJECT/row') as R(nref)
WHERE
    APPLICATION_ID = '9204797'
```

`APPLICATION_ID` is stored as a separate column in the table.

I have tried

```
XMLData.nodes('//PROJECT/row')
```

and all combinations such as

```
XMLData.nodes('//PROJECT[1]')
XMLData.nodes('//row[1]')
```

Any help is appreciated. All I get back are nulls even if I remove the `WHERE` because I only have one record in the table at this point.

Comment: `@ACTIVITY` is the syntax for accessing an attribute, not an element.  Get rid of the `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root tag(`PROJECTS`) spelling is wrong in `nodes` method. Then to extract `APPLICATION_ID` you need to use `value` method like this.

```sql
nref.value('(APPLICATION_ID)[1]', 'Int')
```

`@` is used in `value` method to read attributes but `APPLICATION_ID` is a element in your xml

also you cannot use the alias name in same select queries `Where` clause

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML ='<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
    <APPLICATION_ID>9204797</APPLICATION_ID>
    <ACTIVITY>R44</ACTIVITY>
    <ADMINISTERING_IC>AI</ADMINISTERING_IC>
    <APPLICATION_TYPE>5</APPLICATION_TYPE>
    <ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
    <AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>01/11/2017</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
    <BUDGET_START>01/01/2017</BUDGET_START>
    <BUDGET_END>12/31/2017</BUDGET_END>
    </row>
    </PROJECTS>' -- Here PROJECT should be PROJECTS

SELECT nref.value('(APPLICATION_ID)[1]', 'Int')    APPLICATION_ID,
       nref.value('(ACTIVITY)[1]', 'varchar(max)') ACTIVITY
FROM   @xml.nodes('//PROJECTS/row') AS R(nref) -- Here PROJECT should be PROJECTS
WHERE  nref.value('(APPLICATION_ID)[1]', 'Int') = 9204797
```

Comment: I would have looked at PROJECTS vs PROJECT a thousand times and it would never register.  +1

Comment: PROJECTS- PROJECT that was typo that I missed when cleaning code for posting (but could have missed in app also)   The @ was the big screw up that I would have missed forever.  I had copied some other code that I have that was working but needed to change the values and I added the @ like a dumb ... Thanks I got what I needed